# .htaccess redirect not working with index.php of sub directory

Tags: .htaccess

I have a directory structure like `root/user/confirm/index.php`

I want to make redirect like

Redirect this url

```
http://www.site.com/user/confirm/ASd2sasda4ass
```

To this

```
http://www.site.com/user/confirm/index.php?confirm=ASd2sasda4ass
```

I am trying this way

```
RewriteRule /user/confirm/([^A-Za-z0-9])$ /user/confirm/index.php?confirm=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It redirects this url properly

```
http://www.site.com/user/confirm/index.php/ASd2sasda4ass
```

To

```
http://www.site.com/user/confirm/index.php?confirm=ASd2sasda4ass
```

But not working for this url without `index.php`

```
http://www.site.com/user/confirm/ASd2sasda4ass
```

It shows 404 not found error

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Complete codes

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine on 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteRule /user/confirm/([^A-Za-z0-9])$ /user/confirm/index.php?confirm=$1 [L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It is probably because there's a conflict between the redirect rule and the default view, index.php. Try renaming index.php to something else and see if it works.

Comment: I renamed `index.php` to `confirm.php` still 404 error, working with `confirm.php` in url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by removing this rewrite rule from root .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/user/confirm/([^A-Za-z0-9])$ /user/confirm/index.php?confirm=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And placing another `.htaccess` file in `confirm` directory to hide index.php and processing query parameter there with following codes.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?confirm=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And now its working without `index.php` in url. Hope this helps others too with same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (without confirm.php in the url. You shouldn't need it anyway):

```
RewriteRule ^user/confirm/(.*)/? user_confirm.php?confirm=$1 [L]
```

Comment: There must be other rules that are conflicting then.

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located, in the root directory, yes?

Comment: It's because your directory path `/user/confirm/` is conflicting with the rewrite rule `/user/confirm`. Lose the /user/confirm directory path and move your PHP script to the root (name it something like user_confirm.php) and use the edited rule. If you don't want to move the file, you can rename the directories instead.

Comment: I've just tested it and it works. If you notice, the rewrite rule I've edited above doesn't have the beginning `/`. It should work, give it a try.

Comment: I have resolved this issue by placing another `.htaccess` in confirm directory and then hiding `index.php` its working that way.